# Elixir Phoenix use of scope keyword and syntax question

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm new to Elixir and Phoenix and trying to wrap my head around some of the syntax.  Looking at the basic HelloWeb code section below (code from `router.ex` file)

```
  scope  "/", HelloWeb do ----(1)
    pipe_through :browser 

    get "/", PageController, :index ---(2)
  end
```

Looking at line `(1)` in the code above,

1. Is this calling the function `scope`.  Howcome there is no parenthesis.
2. `HelloWeb` is the name of a module.  What is the purpose in adding it here

Looking at line `(2)` in the code above,

1. How does it find `PageController`.  The module `PageController` is in is `defmodule HelloWeb.PageController do`.  My guess is that adding `HelloWeb` in line `(1)` kind of makes it a shorten form ?
2. What does `:index` mean (there is a function called `index`), specifically the `:`.  Why use the `:`. From my limited knowledge on Elixir `:` signifies an atom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackOverflow may not be the best medium for these types of "YMMV" questions, but let me attempt a couple brief explanations.

In some languages you may have heard "everything is an object."  In Elixir, it's almost like "everything is a function."  Not quite, but thinking that way can help explain things.

`scope` isn't a function, it's a macro, but like a function, it can accept arguments.  In Elixir, parentheses around arguments are optional.  This can help readability -- e.g. even `def` used to define a function is actually a thing that accepts arguments.

The 2nd argument (`HelloWeb`) allows us to omit the full module names.  If you skipped that argument, you would have to list the full module names for your routes, e.g.

```
get "/", HelloWeb.PageController, :index
```

So that answers your next question: yes, providing that as an argument allows us to shorten the form.

Next, why is the `index` function specified with a `:`?  You are correct: this indicates an atom.  Module and function names are stored internally as atoms.  Importantly, when you want to call a function at runtime and you want the exact function to vary (i.e. be a variable), you can use `Kernel.apply/3`, which accepts a Module, the function name (as an atom), and a list of arguments.  E.g. instead of `IO.puts("Hello world")`, you would call `apply(IO, :puts, ["Hello world"])`.  This syntax is similar to other languages (e.g. something like PHP's `call_user_func()`).  It's common to see "MFA" notation, which stands for Module Function Arguments, and the function name is always an atom.